# Criar procedure (SQL) total de vendas (valor) por cliente

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger, procedure

Preciso fazer uma `procedure` que instancie a coluna `cli_TotalCompras` da tabela cliente com o total (em valor) de compras do cliente.

Na tabela **`vendaProduto`** tenho o valor (`vpr_ValorUnit`), a quantidade (`vpr_Quantidade`) e o ID da venda (`ven_ID`) que se associa a tabela **`venda`** que contém o cliente que comprou (`cli_ID`).

Como eu devo fazer?

Tabela `cliente`:

```
create table cliente (
cli_ID           int not null constraint PKCliente primary key,
cli_Nome         varchar(80) not null,
cli_Sexo         char(01) check (cli_Sexo in('M', 'F')),
cli_Nascimento   date Not null,
cid_ID           int not null, 
cli_Email        varchar(100),
cli_Fixo         varchar(11),
cli_Celular      varchar(11),
cli_TotalCompras decimal(10,2);
constraint      fkCliCid foreign key(cid_Id) references cidade(cid_Id));
```

Tabela `venda`:

```
create table venda (
ven_ID   int not null identity (1,1) constraint PKVenda primary key,
cli_ID   int not null,
fun_ID   int not null, 
ven_Data date not null,
constraint fkVenCli foreign key (cli_ID) references cliente(cli_ID),
constraint fkVenFun foreign key (fun_ID) references funcionario(fun_ID));
```

Tabela `vendaProduto`:

```
create table vendaProduto (
vpr_ID          int identity (1,1) constraint PKVendaProduto primary key,
ven_ID          int not null,
liv_ID          int not null, 
vpr_Quantidade  int,
vpr_ValorUnit   decimal(15,2),
constraint fkItvVen foreign key (ven_ID) references venda(ven_ID),
constraint fkItvliv foreign key (liv_ID) references livro(liv_ID));
```

Comment: É para montar procedimento armazenado que será chamado para calcular o valor total de compras do cliente ou criar procedimento trigger que, ocorrendo determinado evento, deve atualizar a coluna cli_TotalCompras?  No aplicativo existe um evento que sinalize final de vendas? Seria o melhor momento para calcular o total daquelas vendas.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score -1):

Se o que necessita é de um procedimento armazenado que deve ser chamado pelo aplicativo ao final de cada venda (isto é, após terem sido registrados todos os itens da venda), eis uma sugestão:

```
-- código #1 v2
CREATE PROCEDURE VendasCliente
                 @pIDvenda int
as
with Soma_vendas as (
SELECT V.cli_ID, Sum(VP.vpr_Quantidade * VP.vpr_ValorUnit) as totalVendas
  from venda as V 
       inner join vendaProduto as VP on VP.ven_ID = V.ven_ID
  where V.ven_ID = @pIDvenda
  group by V.cli_ID
)
UPDATE C
  set cli_TotalCompras+= S.totalVendas
  from cliente as C
       inner join Soma_vendas as S on S.cli_ID = C.cli_ID;
go
```

---

Comment: Show de bola, obrigado. E como seria a trigger se eu quisesse que o valor total (cli_TotalCompras) fosse atualizado a cada nova venda?

Answer (score -1):

Felipe, a respeito de uso de procedimento *trigger*, sugiro que evite ao máximo o uso deles para necessidades que podem ser resolvidas no aplicativo.

Mas se o que postou é um exercício acadêmico, e nele é solicitado que implemente através de procedimento *trigger*, então é necessário criar 3 procedimentos *trigger*, um para cada ação. Ou pode-se implementar o tratamento das três ações em um único procedimento *trigger*.

> Tratamento de vendas

```
-- código #2
CREATE TRIGGER INSERT_vendaProduto
               on vendaProduto
               after INSERT as
begin
-- verifica se há algo a tratar
declare @NL int;
set @NL= (SELECT Count(*) from (SELECT top (2) * from INSERTED) as I);
IF @NL = 0
  return;

-- trata um ou mais itens de vendas, para um ou mais clientes
UPDATE C
  set cli_TotalCompras+= (I.vpr_Quantidade * I.vpr_ValorUnit)
  from Cliente as C
       inner join venda as V on V.cli_ID = C.cli_ID
       inner join INSERTED as I on I.ven_ID = V.ven_ID;
end;
go
```

> Tratamento de alteração na quantidade ou valor de item vendido

```
-- código #3
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_vendaProduto
               on vendaProduto
               after UPDATE as
begin
-- verifica se há algo a tratar
declare @NL int;
set @NL= (SELECT Count(*) from (SELECT top (2) * from INSERTED) as I);
IF @NL = 0
  return;

-- encerra se não houve tentativa de alteração nas colunas de quantidade ou valor unitário
IF not (UPDATE(vpr_Quantidade) or UPDATE(vpr_ValorUnit))
  return;

-- trata um ou mais itens de vendas, para um ou mais clientes
UPDATE C
  set cli_TotalCompras+= ((I.vpr_Quantidade * I.vpr_ValorUnit) - (D.vpr_Quantidade * D.vpr_ValorUnit))
  from Cliente as C
       inner join venda as V on V.cli_ID = C.cli_ID
       inner join DELETED as D on D.ven_ID = V.ven_ID
       inner join INSERTED as I on I.ven_ID = V.ven_ID
end;
go
```

> Tratamento de devolução (cancelamento) de item vendido

```
-- código #4
CREATE TRIGGER DELETE_vendaProduto
               on vendaProduto
               after DELETE as
begin
-- verifica se há algo a tratar
declare @NL int;
set @NL= (SELECT Count(*) from (SELECT top (2) * from DELETED) as D);
IF @NL = 0
  return;

-- trata um ou mais itens de vendas, para um ou mais clientes
UPDATE C
  set cli_TotalCompras-= (D.vpr_Quantidade * D.vpr_ValorUnit)
  from Cliente as C
       inner join venda as V on V.cli_ID = C.cli_ID
       inner join DELETED as D on D.ven_ID = V.ven_ID
end;
go
```

.

Comment: @FelipeMouraShurrab, avaliou a solução acima, usando procedimento trigger?